# Remove the sorting arrow on a datagrid when resetting the sorting order

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have been working on this for hours now. I have figured out how to reset the sorting order of a collection using CollectionView now the problem is that the arrow that displays the order of the sort wont go away. Using this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) page I am pretty sure I need to the SortDirection property on Datagrid columns. So I bound that but I cant seem to get sorting arrow to change when I set the property.. here are some code examples of what I have done:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"
              Visibility="{Binding DatagridIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityInverseParameterConverter}}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Margin="0,0,0,44" 
              FontSize="20" 
              AlternationCount="2"
              AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns >
   <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Raw Data" 
                        Binding="{Binding RawData}"
                        SortDirection="{Binding Sorter, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>   
  <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Manufacturer" 
                       Binding="{Binding Manu}"
                       SortDirection="{Binding Sorter, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
   </DataGridTextColumn>       
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in my view model this is the property SortDirection is bound to

```
private ListSortDirection? _sorter;
public ListSortDirection? Sorter
{
   get { return _sorter; }
   set
   {
      if (_sorter == value)
      {
          return;
      }
      _sorter = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

So according to what I have read setting Sort to null should remove the around but I get nothing its acting as though its ignoring the binding even if I use the enum to send ascending or descending but I get nothing out of it.

Comment: Are you getting binding errors? Setting the SortDirection to null should remove the arrow has you have said. Since you said you are getting nothing you are likely getting binding errors

Comment: The DataGridTextColumn Binding propertys were giving me binding errors. When I changed the Item source of the datagrid from the Observable Collection to the CollectionView even though it still worked properly when I ran the application. For testing I swapped the ItemSource back to the ObservableCollection to get rid of the binding errors unfortunately the SortDirection binding still does not seem to work.